# Returning a type in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, types, promise, observable

I have a dataSync service that returns a promise of type `<WebPost>` on resolve . but when i use the service in my component, typescript keeps refering to the returned data as type object instead of type `<WebPost>` which breaks my code.
Also in the dataSync service the `resolve(data) line`, i get this error when i hover on the data

```
Argument of type '{ _id: string; caption: string; comments: [string]; likes: [string]; price: number; image: string; forUser: string; likesLength: 1; commentsLength: 1; isLiked: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WebPost | PromiseLike<WebPost>'.
```

How do i resolve this?

here is the method in my component

```
getPostFromUrl() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.dataSyncService.getPostData(id).then(data => {
        this.data._id = id;
        this.data.caption = data.caption;
        this.data.comments = data.comments;
        this.data.likes = data.likes;
        this.data.price = data.price;
        this.data.image = data.image;
        this.data.forUser = data.forUser;
        this.data.isLiked = data.isLiked;
        this.data.likesLength = data.likesLength;

        this.isData = true;
      });
    });
  }
```

here is the dataSyncService

```
getPostDataP(id): Promise<WebPost> {
    return new Promise<WebPost>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authService.getPostP(id).subscribe(d => {
        if (d.success) {
          const data = {
            _id: '',
            caption: d.data.caption,
            comments: d.data.comments,
            likes: d.data.likes,
            price: d.data.price,
            image: d.data.imageUrl,
            forUser: d.data.forUser,
            likesLength: d.data.likes.length,
            commentsLength: d.data.comments.length,
            isLiked: d.data.isLiked
          };
          resolve(data);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

hereis the webPost type

```
export interface WebPost {
  _id: string;
    image: string;
    forUser: string;
    price: number;
    likes: [string];
    comments: [object];
    caption: string;
    likesLength: number;
    commentsLength: number;
    likessLength: number;
    isLiked: boolean;

}
```

Comment: Your interface has a `likessLength` property which is not being set in your `getPostDataP` function.

Comment: I just removed it, still not working

Comment: Seems to work when I try it in StackBlitz? Make sure you remove `likessLength` and not `likesLength`

Comment: In your `WebPost` interface declaration, in `likes` and `comments`, I don't think `[string]` and `[object]` is the correct syntax. If you want them to be an array of strings / an array of objects then you should use `string[]` and `object[]` instead

Comment: The problem was when declaring the data object in dataSyncService, i didn't add the type. after i did `const data: WebPost = {}`. it works after then thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `WebPost` interface declaration, you should be using `string[]` and `object[]` instead of `[string]` and `[object]` if you want them to be an array of strings / objects.